# @@ROWCOUNT returning 1 when no UPDATE made

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have some SQL within a stored procedure where I am updating a table based on another `SELECT` statement from a temp table (code below).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @RowCount int

UPDATE TABLEX SET 
TRA = ISNULL (ir.DcTra, DCBASIC.TRA),
TRD = ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(REPLACE(ir.DcTRD, '-', ''), '') AS datetime), DCBASIC.TRD), 
LSINC = ISNULL(ir.DcLsInc, DCBASIC.LSINC), 
REVSWOVR = ISNULL(ir.DcRevswovr, DCBASIC.REVSWOVR) FROM #TempData ir WHERE TABLEX.MEMBNO = ir.IntMembNo

SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

The `@RowCount` variable is being set to 1.

The `SELECT` of the #TempData table returns no rows and no rows in the TABLEX table are updated (or even exist) with the MembNo (I have added `SELECT` statements within the sp to debug and they confirm this)

Why is `@RowCount` being set to 1?

Comment: How do you know that no update was performed? Add: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempData`.

Comment: @usr - as I stated in my post, "(I have added SELECT statements within the sp to debug and they confirm this)"

Comment: Ok, did not see that statement. Are there triggers? To be clear: It is extremely unlikely that you have found a bug in SQL Server so the bug is with you.; Create a after-trigger that just throws an exception if any rows are incoming for update. That way you can make sure that there really is no update.

Comment: Can you execute next query and give us a result `select count(*) from #TempData where IntMembNo in (select MEMBNO from TABLEX)`

Comment: @veljasije - `select count(*) from #TempData where IntMembNo in (select MEMBNO from TABLEX)` reurns ZERO

Comment: Do you have any other statements between `SET @RowNumber = @@ROWNUMBER` and `SELECT @RowNumber` statements?

Comment: @veljasije - yes I do, only these lines of code `IF @Err <> 0 
BEGIN
 GOTO ErrHand
END`

Comment: I am simulating your scenario and I have got value 0, and I can't  really realize what affect on your @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: I also removed those lines so there is nothing between the `SET` and `SELECT` statements - still having `@RowCount` returning 1

Comment: @veljasije - thanks - could you post the code you did to simulate so I can see if there are any differences? I'm wondering if it might be environment rather than code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

```
Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1.
```

More information you can find here:

[@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

My example:

```
CREATE DATABASE FirstDB
GO

USE FirstDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE Person (
    personId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName varchar(20) ,
    lastName varchar(20) ,
    age int
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Person (firstName, lastName, age)
VALUES ('Nick', 'Smith', 30),
    ('Jack', 'South', 25),
    ('Garry', 'Perth', 20)


CREATE TABLE PersonAge (
    personAgeId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    personId INT ,
    newAge varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.PersonAge(personId, newAge)
VALUES (1, 60),
    (2, 65),
    (3, 70)

ALTER TABLE dbo.PersonAge
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonAgePerson FOREIGN KEY (personId)
REFERENCES dbo.Person (personId)
```

And then example of query:

```
USE FirstDB;
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @row int;

UPDATE Person
SET age = 40
FROM dbo.Person as p join dbo.PersonAge as p1
    ON p.personId = p1.personId
WHERE p.age = 60

SET @row = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @row
```

I create an `UPDATE` query where none of rows will be affected.

At the end @row consist 0 value.

Comment: Thanks @veljasije - which part of my UPDATE is a "simple assignment"? "Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1. No rows are sent to the client. Examples of these statements are: SET local_variable, RETURN, READTEXT, and select without query statements such as SELECT GETDATE() or SELECT 'Generic Text'."

Comment: Thanks @veljasije - there was a rogue `SET @Err = @@ERROR` between my `UPDATE` statement and the setting of my variable. Amazing when someone else does code that works - it focussed your mind! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, using INSERT and DELETE--

```
DECLARE @deletedRows INT = 0;
SELECT @deletedRows = @@ROWCOUNT;   --no previous DML statement
SELECT @deletedRows;    --@@ROWCOUNT = 1 for a simple assignment
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;
GO
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT IDENTITY, CurrentDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE());
GO

INSERT #Test DEFAULT VALUES;    --INSERT a single row
DECLARE @deletedRows INT = @@ROWCOUNT;  --@@ROWCOUNT = 1 
SELECT @deletedRows;
GO

DELETE FROM #Test WHERE 1=2;    --no rows deleted
DECLARE @deletedRows INT = @@ROWCOUNT;  --@@ROWCOUNT = 0
SELECT @deletedRows;
GO

DELETE TOP (1) t FROM #Test t WHERE 1=1;    --1 row deleted
DECLARE @deletedRows INT = @@ROWCOUNT;  --@@ROWCOUNT = 1
SELECT @deletedRows;
GO

DELETE TOP (1) t FROM #Test t WHERE 1=1;    --no rows left to delete
DECLARE @deletedRows INT = @@ROWCOUNT;  --@@ROWCOUNT = 0
SELECT @deletedRows;
GO
```